# Segfault on char comparison in C

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
void click(int x, int y, zbar_window_t *window, ZBarGtk *self) {
    char* response = handle_click_events(x, y, window);
    printf("RESPONSE + %s\n", response);
    printf("%c\n", response[0]);
    if (response[0] == "0") {                                 //CRASHES HERE
        printf("inside \n");
        printf("%s\n", response++);
        g_signal_emit(self, self->enumACTIVE, 0, -1, response++);
    }
    else {
        g_signal_emit(self, self->enumACTIVE, 0, -1, response++);
    }
}
```

It keeps on crashing on the stated line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this:

`if(response[0] == "0")`

with:

`if(response[0] == '0')`

`"0"` is a string, `'0'` is a character. You should not compare strings using `==`.

Also, you should check if `response` is `NULL` after this statement:

```
char* response = handle_click_events(x, y, window);
```

otherwise `printf("%c\n", response[0]);` may crash again.

Comment: I don’t think we should advise people to use `strcmp`. Or at least, point out that the function is not secure.

Comment: @qdii It could be worse, you could be advising people to use strncpy, which is far more dangerous than strcpy. Most C standard library functions are not "secure". The foundation to secure programming is to actually know what you are doing.